# Rascal MPL overload library functions

Tags: function, overloading, standard-library, rascal

It's easy to overload your own functions like so:

```
void testVal(loc l) {
    println("LOC <l>");
}

void testVal(value v) {
    println("VAL <v>");
}
```

such that `testVal(|tmp:///|)` will call the first method. I wish to do the same to `IO::println`:

```
void println(loc l) {
    IO::println("my custom println function");
}
```

to serve for debug purposes. `println(|tmp:///|)` should now print `"my custom println function"`. Is it possible to do this? For me this code still defaults to the `IO` implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function overloading works by non-deterministic selection. So if the patterns of `testVal` or `println` overlap, then there is no way to know which one is chosen first.

In fact in your example, `loc l` overlaps with `value v` so the priority between the two alternatives is undefined.

To fix this, one of the alternatives must get a more precise pattern (e.g. change `value v` to `num v` to distinguish it from `loc l`, or you can put the `default` modifier before the function:

```
default void testVal(value v) {
   println("VAL <v>");
}
```

If you want to override an existing function that does not have the `default` modifier, I am afraid you are out of luck. You can't change the IO module to add the `default`. So to work around this issue you can wrap the IO::println function in your own function:

```
default void pln(value... v) {
   println(v);
}

void pln(loc l) {
   println("LOC <l>");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What's the `value... v` notation? Is it some sort of unpacking?

Comment: O that's "varargs" like in C and Java, it means `list[value] v` but you don't have to put the square brackets when calling the function: `pln(1, 2, 3)`